# How can I use SED to uncomment + fill blank double quotes with text in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, automation

Say for instance there is a hostfile with a comment

```
#run_as_user=""
```

Updated to comment removed, alone with empty quotes replaced with user

```
run_as_user="ec2-user"
```

using SED - Also welcoming AWK examples thanks

Comment: I think you are making it more complicated than it is. You don't have to "remove the comment" and "fill the quotes". You can just find the line and replace it with a different value: `sed -e 's/^#run_as_user=/run_as_user="ec2-user"/'`

Comment: Thanks for speedy reply - however your suggestion gave me run_as_user="ec2-user""" which is not what I am after :)  - it needs to be run_as_user="ec2-user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ed(1)`

```
printf '%s\n' '/^#run_as_user/s/^#//' '/run_as_user/s/"$/ec2-user"/' w | ed -s hostfile.txt
```

Or as per request `sed(1)`

```
sed -i '' '/^#run_as_user/s/^#//;s/"$/ec2-user"/' hostfile.txt
```

- `BSD sed` requires an additional tempfile as an argument with the `-i` option, hence the `''` after the `-i`,  however that is not needed with `GNU sed`
- `'/^#run_as_user/'` Match the pattern that starts with a `#`, (the `^` is an anchor in regex which means the beginning) followed by `run_as_user`
- `'s/^#//'` Remove the string `#` at the beginning
- The `;` separate the next command from the previous.
- `s/"$/ec2-user"/'` Insert at the end (`$` is anchor in regex that means at the end) after the quote `"` `ec2-user`
- `sed(1)` and `ed(1)` is using B.R.E. Basic Regular Expression.

Comment: Jetchisel that worked a charm! Any how you can show me a sed example also thanks as to what Felix suggested?

Comment: @Nza updated the answer for the sed.

Comment: Hi Jetchisel I tried the suggested sed command against the same dummy file and it gave error: sed: 1: "hostfile": extra characters at the end of n command - Thanks in advance :D

Comment: And the error was?

Comment: sed: 1: "hostfile": extra characters at the end of n command

Comment: Right, you most probably have BSD sed, updated the answer

Comment: If you can kindly give a break down of the sed structure - that would be highly appreciated as sed is still a little Encryptic to me but I am getting the understanding more and more... Also I noticed the updated answer now has a space after the -i switch, so I assume that what generated the n related error

Comment: @Nza add an explanation.